# Mongoose say validation required error, even value was provided

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a JSON data file on this link https://github.com/vontend/upload/blob/master/countries.json

My Model with mongoosejs like this

```
const { model, Schema } = require("mongoose");

const CountrySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Bạn phải nhập tên quốc gia"],
        unique: true,
    },
    code: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Bạn phải nhập code"],
        unique: true,
    },
    capital: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    region: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        ref: "Region",
    },
    currency: new Schema({
        code: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        symbol: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
    }),
    language: new Schema({
        code: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
    }),
    flag: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
});

const Country = model("Country", CountrySchema);

module.exports = Country;
```

And the route

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const Country = require("../models/Country");

const router = Router();


router.get("/country", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let countries = await fs.readFileSync(
            __dirname + "/../install/countries.json",
            "utf-8"
        );
        countries = JSON.parse(countries);
        // countries = await Country.insertMany(countries);
        return res.json({
            success: true,
            message: "Init countries successful",
            data: {
                countries,
                length: countries.length,
            },
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({
            success: false,
            message: "Init countries failed",
            error,
        });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

When running the code to insert data to the database, I got this message

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Init countries failed",
    "error": {
        "errors": {
            "capital": {
                "message": "Path `capital` is required.",
                "name": "ValidatorError",
                "properties": {
                    "message": "Path `capital` is required.",
                    "type": "required",
                    "path": "capital",
                    "value": ""
                },
                "kind": "required",
                "path": "capital",
                "value": ""
            }
        },
        "_message": "Country validation failed",
        "message": "Country validation failed: capital: Path `capital` is required.",
        "name": "ValidationError"
    }
}
```

It's so confusing. I don't know why it is? I have double-checked the `capital` path exists on every element. So what wrong with it? Can anyone explain this stuff for me, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty (undefined) values break the required rule.

In mongoose [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#validation), it says:

> Validators are not run on undefined values. The only exception is the
>   required validator.

Some of the capital data has empty (undefined) values like this:

```
  {
    "name": "Bouvet Island",
    "code": "BV",
    "capital": "",
    "region": "AN",
    "currency": {
      "code": "NOK",
      "name": "Norwegian krone",
      "symbol": "kr"
    },
    "language": {
      "code": "no",
      "name": "Norwegian"
    },
    "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/bvt.svg"
  },
```

Just remove the required option for capital field so that it can work.

Or as a fix, apply this code before schema definition so that empty value doesn't break the required rule.

```js
mongoose.Schema.Types.String.checkRequired((v) => v != null);
```